# Wordpress show/hide comments form

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with my wordpress theme.
I can't create a button to show/hide comments form.

I have a **comments.php** file with this code:

```
if ( ! comments_open() && '0' != get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) :
    ?>
        <p class="no-comments"><?php _e( 'Comments are close.', 'ffita' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

This file works properly but I can't modify to add a button.

I try to change it in this way:

first I create new file **comment_form.php** with this code:

```
comment_form();
```

then modify **comment.php** in this way

```
if ( ! comments_open() && '0' != get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) :
    ?>
        <p class="no-comments"><?php _e( 'Comments are close.', 'ffita' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

   <div class="commenti">
      <button type="button" id="ffita-add-comment" class="btn btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#ffita-add-comment").click(function(){
               event.preventDefault();
               $.ajax({  
                  type: 'GET',  
                  url: '/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ffita/template-parts/comment_form.php',  
                  success: function(response){  
                     $( '#ffita-comment-form' ).html( response ); 
                  },  
    
               });  
            });
         });   
         </script>
      
      <div id="ffita-comment-form">

      </div>

      
    <?php //comment_form(); ?>
```

But click on button result in:
**Fatal error**: Call to undefined function comment_form()

So my question is: how to create a button to load wordpress comment_form() function only when clicked?
I have few comments on my blog and I don't want to load unnecessary code (like form and captcha) if it is not necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my previous question I had two problems:

- show / hide the comments form in wordpress posts
- run the google recaptcha plugin only when needed (when the user wants to post a comment)

The solution adopted, from a logical point of view, is the following:

- disable plugin used previously
- default: hide wp comment form section through css
- add button "add comment" ... when clicked it shows comment form with submit button disabled
- when user select text area for input comment -> loag google captcha
- validate captcha and, if it is ok -> enable submit button in wp comment form

After various researches and tests I solved in this way....  thanks to various posts found on stackoverflow

1. I uninstalled the plugin used to insert google recaptcha
2. In the **function.php**, when i enqueue js script I added:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ffita_base_functions_js',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/ffita_base_functions.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ));  //enqueue js script

wp_localize_script('ffita_base_functions_js',  'ffita_var', array("ffita_theme_path"=> get_template_directory_uri()) );  //use wp_localize_sript to pass var data from PHP to JavaScript
```

3. In the **style.css** file I have inserted the following code:

```
.comment-respond{
   visibility: hidden;   //default wordpress class for comment form 
}

#ffita-captcha{
    margin: 30px;
}
```

4. In my template I changed **comments.php** in this way:

```
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ffita-add-comment">Add a comment</button>
     <div id="ffita-captcha"> </div> //div where google captcha will be displayed
```

```
<?php 
   $comments_args = array(
        'class_submit' => 'submit ffita-captcha-submit',    //add a class to standar submit button
   );     
   comment_form($comments_args); ?>    //wordpress function to call comments form
   
 
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {                      //jquery function
   var id_activation='comment';                     //div id where click active captcha
   var id_captcha_view='ffita-captcha';             //div id where captcha will be displayed 
   $('.ffita-captcha-submit').prop('disabled',true);  //disable comment form submit button
    $('#'+id_activation).on('click', function(){      //when click on comment text area
      ffita_show_captcha(id_captcha_view);            //call js function and pass id where display captcha 
   });
   $('.ffita-add-comment').on('click', function(){     //jquery for button...., when clicked
       $(this).hide();                                 //hide button 
       $('.comment-respond').attr("style", "visibility: visible");  //show comment form
   });
});    
</script>
```

5. in file **ffita_base_function.js** (previously enqueue in function.php) I added this function.
   NOTE: I used developer key by google in this sample script.  https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq    use own keys in production environment

```
function ffita_form_activate(resp){  //function call from the next
  var simple_chk=false;              //false or true. see below notes
    if (simple_chk){
    if (resp.length != 0 ) {        //if response lenght is not 0 I evaluate captcha solved
      $('.ffita-captcha-submit').prop('disabled',false);  //enable wp comment submit button
    } 
    else {
      alert ("try again");
      grecaptcha.reset();         //on failed reset captcha
    }
  }
  else {
    if (resp.length != 0 ) {
      local_path=ffita_var.ffita_theme_path;     //var passed through wp_localize_script (theme root dir)
      $.ajax({
        url: local_path+'/inc/g_recaptcha_verify.php',   //php file for captcha verification see below
        type:'POST',
        data:{resp:resp},
          success: function (response) {              //php file returns OK if captcha was solved correctly
            if (response=="OK"){
              $('.ffita-captcha-submit').prop('disabled',false);
            }
            else {
              alert ("try again")
              grecaptcha.reset();
            }
          }
      });
    }
    else {
      alert ("try again");
      grecaptcha.reset();
    }
  }
}



var captchaLoaded = false;

function ffita_show_captcha(id_captcha_view){ //function call from jquery - comment.php
  // If we have loaded script once already, exit.
  if (captchaLoaded) {
    return;
  }
  // Variable Intialization
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var recaptchaScript = document.createElement('script');

  
  //key for develop (site key)
  var recaptchaKey = '6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI';   //is key for developer...insert you public key!!
  
  // Dynamically add Recaptcha Script
  recaptchaScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  recaptchaScript.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
  
  // Dynamically load  script 
  head.appendChild(recaptchaScript);
  
  //check grecaptcha is defined otherwise I wait
  var poll;
  var timeout = 200;
  poll = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      timeout--;
      if (typeof grecaptcha !== 'undefined') {
        grecaptcha.render(id_captcha_view,    //where catpcha  is shown
          {
           'sitekey': recaptchaKey,
           'theme': "light",
           'callback': ffita_form_activate, //call for prev function, return response from google function
          }
         );
      }
      else if (timeout > 0) {
        poll();
      }
      else {
        alert ("Failed to load. Please retry");
      }
    }, 200);
  };
  poll();
   
  //Set flag to only load once
   captchaLoaded = true;
}
```

NOTE: in ffita_form_activate function I have two different ways to test captcha response... based on simple_chk var.
If simple_chk is true I check the length of the response received from grecaptcha.render.... if response lenght is not 0 I evaluate captcha solved

If simple_chk is false I pass the response value to php file (g_recaptcha_verify.php) for verification

6. I create **g_recaptcha_verify.php**  for server side verification of captcha
   NOTE: I used developer key by google in this sample script.  https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq
   use own keys in production environment

```
<?php

//developer value
//Site key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI
//Secret key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe


// check post value:  
    if (isset($_POST['resp'])) {        
      
// Create POST request:      
       
       $recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';      
       $recaptcha_secret = '6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe';      //insert your secret key!!
       $recaptcha_response = $_POST['resp'];        
       
// Send POST request and decode respone:      
        
       $recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . '?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret . '&response=' . $recaptcha_response);      
       $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha);        
      
// Google response evaluation:      
       
       if ($recaptcha && $recaptcha->success) {  
        
         echo ("OK");   //used in jquery 
   
       } else {  
        
       //    
           echo ("NO_OK"); //use in jquery 
  
      }    
} 
?>
```

7. FINISHED!! You can see a working example on any post on [my site](https://www.frequentflyeritalia.com/) :)